# How to use array of cookies of ASP.NET in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, cookies

I want to read an ASP.NET cookies array in PHP.  Any idea how I can access the `COOKIES ARRAY` of ASP.NET in PHP?

Comment: Are you just trying to access the cookies sent from a client with PHP or there's something else? ASP.NET and PHP are totally unrelated - so if you're trying to access ASP.NET array from PHP - http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html

Comment: In what way? Are these apps on the same domain and can share cookies? Do you want to parse the server-side ASP session store from PHP?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Try adding more details, maybe someone will figure out what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trying to search in google, and I find below code snippet that how to use cookie value in php and asp.net. Hope this will help you..

Ref Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479002.aspx

[image]